# function is not called onChange of Checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am repeating a OBJECT to render UI. Each row has a ItemName and a checkbox. Onclick of checkbox I should get the ID of that row. When I Run the page I am getting this error msg => Cannot read property 'addToCompare' of undefined

```
import React from 'react';

    export default class List extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

        }
        addToCompare(event){
              console.log('get id of row');
            }
        render() {
          var planList = [
                          {id: 1, "itemname": "Sunshine},
                          {id: 2, "itemname": "Global"},
                          {id: 3, "itemname": "Lifetime"}
                          ];
            return (
                    <div id="layout-content" className="layout-content-wrapper">
                      {
                        planList.map(function(item, i) {
                         return (
                           <div className="row" key={i}>
                              <h1>
                               <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.addToCompare.bind(this)} />{item.name}
                              </h1>
                           </div>
                           )
                         })
                       }
                     )
    }
```

Comment: There is missing quote after Sunshine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use es6 syntax, for `map` function to refer `this` to List as

```
planList.map((item, i) =>{
   return (
         <div className="row" key={i}>
          <h1>
           <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.addToCompare.bind(this)} />{item.name}
          </h1>
          </div>
         )
      })
```

or store `this` to other variable and use it to get `addToCompare` property as stated by @Marco

Answer (score 2):

And If you're using `Class` declarations, you can use all **ES6** features.

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.addToCompare = this.addToCompare.bind(this)
  }

  addToCompare(event) {
    console.log('get id of row')
  }

  render() {
    const planList = [
      { id: 1, itemname: 'Sunshine' },
      { id: 2, itemname: 'Global' },
      { id: 3, itemname: 'Lifetime' },
    ]

    const rows = planList.map((item, i) =>
      <div className="row" key={i}>
        <h1>
          <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.addToCompare} />
          {item.itemname}
        </h1>
      </div>
    )

    return (
      <div id="layout-content" className="layout-content-wrapper">
        {rows}
      </div>
   )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" />
```

Answer (score 1):

When you map the list to `<div>` tags using the `map` method, [the value of this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) inside that mapping function is `undefined`, not the component, as it is [invoked as an anonymous function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#The_function_declaration_(function_statement)).

Inside your render method, declare a `that` variable, to hold a reference to your component.

```
var planList = ... ,
    that = this;
```

Now you can reference the component using `that` instead of `this`

```
<input type="checkbox" onChange={that.addToCompare.bind(that)} />{item.name}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing wrong context to the `onChange` method

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  addToCompare(event) {
    console.log('get id of row');
  }

  render() {
    var planList = [{
      id: 1,
      "itemname": "Sunshine"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      "itemname": "Global"
    }, {
      id: 3,
      "itemname": "Lifetime"
    }, ];

    var _this = this

    var rows = planList.map(function(item, i) {
      return (
         <div className="row" key={i}>
            <h1>
             <input type="checkbox" onChange={_this.addToCompare.bind(_this)} />{item.itemname}
            </h1>
         </div>
         )
      }
    )

    return (
      <div id="layout-content" className="layout-content-wrapper">
        {rows}
      </div>
   )
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" />
```